# Select empty clans from database

Tags: mysql, database, relationship

I have two tables: accounts and clans

There is a hasMany relationship between these two.

One clan can have multiple accounts: accounts.clanId points to clans.clanId

How can I select all empty clans that don't have any accounts?

Comment: See [this great explanation of joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to do a `LEFT JOIN` between the two tables and retain those clan records which did not map to any accounts:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM clans c
LEFT JOIN accounts a
    ON c.clanId = a.clanId
WHERE a.clanId IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM CLANS C
WHERE C.clanId NOT IN (SELECT ClanID FROM ACCOUNTS)
```